# Shell script error while using SED

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, centos

Hi I am trying to use multiple sed commands at a time on a single file(cinder.conf). My shell file(test.sh) looks like

```
sed -i '/[DEFAULT]/s/$/\nrpc_backend = rabbit\nauth_strategy = keystone\nmy_ip = INPUTREQ\nverbose = True\nenabled_backends = lvm\nglance_host = controller/' /etc/cinder/cinder.conf

sed -i '/[oslo_messaging_rabbit]/s/$/\nrabbit_host = controller\nrabbit_userid = openstack\nrabbit_password = 1234/' /etc/cinder/cinder.conf
```

and my original output file looks like

```
[DEFAULT]

[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
```

When I am trying to execute the shell file(test.sh) the output looks like

```
[DEFAULT]
rpc_backend = rabbit
rabbit_host = controller
rabbit_userid = openstack
rabbit_password = 1234
auth_strategy = keystone
rabbit_host = controller
rabbit_userid = openstack
rabbit_password = 1234
my_ip = INPUTREQ
rabbit_host = controller
rabbit_userid = openstack
rabbit_password = 1234
verbose = True
rabbit_host = controller
rabbit_userid = openstack
rabbit_password = 1234
enabled_backends = lvm
rabbit_host = controller
rabbit_userid = openstack
rabbit_password = 1234
glance_host = controller
rabbit_host = controller
rabbit_userid = openstack
rabbit_password = 1234

[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
rabbit_host = controller
rabbit_userid = openstack
rabbit_password = 1234
```

But when I am trying to execute single SED command on the original file(cinder.conf) its working perfectly. Only when I use multiple SED commands at a time buy running the test.sh file, My original file is outputted as shown above. I am using Centos. I am new to scripting. Kindly me through the error.

My scenario is to add few lines to cinder.con file (using shell scripting). The final output should like

```
[DEFAULT]
rpc_backend = rabbit
auth_strategy = keystone
my_ip = INPUTREQ
verbose = True
enabled_backends = lvm
glance_host = controller

[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
rabbit_host = controller
rabbit_userid = openstack
rabbit_password = 1234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape `[` and `]` with a `\`:

```
sed -i '/\[DEFAULT\]/s/$/\nrpc_backend = rabbit\nauth_strategy = keystone\nmy_ip = INPUTREQ\nverbose = True\nenabled_backends = lvm\nglance_host = controller/' /etc/cinder/cinder.conf

sed -i '/\[oslo_messaging_rabbit\]/s/$/\nrabbit_host = controller\nrabbit_userid = openstack\nrabbit_password = 1234/' /etc/cinder/cinder.conf
```

Comment: Thanks a ton...its working..I have these characters ( { ) and ( : )  and ( ' )  should I use escape for all those characters.